# Meta-term for unification of duality

Tags: single-word-requests

We have polar opposites: hot & cold, ascending & descending, young & old, exhale & inhale, smooth & rough. We have words such as "opposite" and "duality" that describe these relationships.

Then, we have words that combine opposites into a single concept: temperature, inclining, age, breath, texture<sup>*</sup>. These unified concepts maintain or respect the opposition, often as ends of a pole or spectrum, rather than collapsing them to a singularity. What's the term (if any) for the class of these words?

One use of the word is to ask for a word that combines opposites: "What's the literal-figurative ____?", "What's the ____ for objective & subjective?"

In some contexts, "axis" is used, but doesn't seem generally to carry the desired meaning and requires the context to make sense. "Synthesis" is unsuitable because it involves creating a *new* concept that *reconciles* the conflict, rather than contains the opposites. "Dichotomy" doesn't include cases where the unification is continuous. "太極" ("tàijí" in pinyin), in some conceptions and translations, can carry this meaning in Chinese, with the meaning of unifying the polarity of yin and yang; the Wikipedia article on [tàijí](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiji_(philosophy)) captures in a quote from Zhang and Ryden's "Key Concepts in Chinese Philosophy":

> Any philosophy that asserts two elements such as the yin-yang of Chinese philosophy will also look for a term to reconcile the two, to ensure that both belong to the same sphere of discourse. The term 'supreme ultimate' [tàijí] performs this role in the philosophy of the Book of Changes.

The phrase "two sides of the same coin" is closely related in sense; the word I'm looking for would be the coin.

<sub>* "Texture" could be said to combine other opposites as well, such as "hard" and "soft".</sub>

Comment: Have you considered "ambivalency"?

Comment: Two types of words come to my mind, so can you make clear for which type (if any) are you asking: 1) spectrum, range, extent, scope 2) summary, connection, combination, union. Can you make one or two additional examples of sentences with the desired word?

Comment: Are you looking for *dvandva* words?

Comment: @J.Taylor: doesn't quite fit, as the word I'm looking for is a linguistic category, rather than concerning the state of something.

Comment: @Jan: more 2) than 1), as it should cover unifying discrete opposites in addition to continuous, though 1) may be included. I'll try to come up with more example sentences.

Comment: @Autoresponder: no, as none of "temperature", "inclining", &c. are compounds, but the term is interesting.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are asking. Maybe you could eleborate on the parts of 太極 you are interested in? What kind of unification are you looking for? I would say *scalar* if  defining some kind of spectrum